# Usefulness of total algebras and exotic generating series

Tags: reference-request, big-list, semigroups-and-monoids, generating-functions, noncommutative-rings

In his first Algebra volume, Bourbaki [1] defines the structure of a *“total algebra”* i.e. the space of functions on a monoid $M$ (to a ring $k$) with the convolution product ( a function $f:\ M\to k$ will be noted as an infinite sum $\sum_{m\in M}f(m)m$ [2] ). Indeed, formally writing
$$
\left(\sum_{m_1\in M}f(m_1)m_1\right) \left(\sum_{m_2\in M}g(m_2)m_2\right)=
\sum_{m\in M}\left(\sum_{m_1m_2=m}f(m_1)g(m_2)\right)m
$$
one rightly finds “Property D” of [1] saying that for all
$m\in M$, one asks that the set
$$
D_2(m)=\{(m_1,m_2)\in M\times M\,|\, m_1m_2=m \}
$$
be finite [3].

This opens the door for many algebras of series already being used in mathematics (algebras of commutative, non-commutative, partially commutative series, characters of Verma modules &c.).

**My question is the following:**
What are examples and references of “exotic monoids” (preferably infinite, but satisfying “Property D”) whose “space of series” is successfully used in 
 general mathematics ?

**Remark** Condition (D) generalizes easily to categories.

**Late edit** Let again $M$ be a monoid satisfying "Condition (D)" and $k$ a commutative ring.
 For all $m\in M$, set
$$
Fact(m):=\{u\,|\,m\in MuM\}
$$
(the set of factors of $m$). Using (D), it is straightforward that
$Fact(m)$ is finite and that
$$
Fact(m_1)\cup Fact(m_2)\subset Fact(m_1m_2) \qquad (1)
$$
and that
$$
\mathfrak{m}_m:= span_k(M\setminus Fact(m))
$$
is the largest two-sided ideal which avoids $m$ (i.e. $J$ s.t. $m\notin J$).
Now, one can check that, due to (1), $\left(\mathfrak{m}_m\right)_{m\in M}$ is a system of neighbourhoods of zero for a Hausdorff topology $\mathcal{T}$ such that $(k[M],\mathcal{T})$ is a topological ring (every set of two sided ideals closed by intersection does that, here finite intersections of elements picked in $\left(\mathfrak{m}_m\right)_{m\in M}$ ). One checks easily that $k[[M]]$ (the total algebra) is the completion of $k[M]$ for this topology
(i.e. $k[[M]]=\widehat{k[M]}$). 
In this way, total algebras rank among numerous completed rings commonly used by the working mathematician.

[1] Bourbaki Algebra, Chapter III § 2.10.

[2] This may be justified by the topology of pointwise convergence on the space of all functions $M\to k$, ($k$ being endowed with the discrete topology).

[3] All finite monoids (in particular finite groups), of course, satisfy this property. An infinite group doesn’t.

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_algebra

Comment: If you have a monoid with a presentation where both sides of each relation have the same length you clearly have Property D. Trace monoids aka Cartier-Foata monoids aka graph monoid aka right angled Artin monoids have this form.  I believe that some residual properties of right angled Artin groups were first proved using a generalization of the Magnus representation by series over the corresponding trace monoid if I recall correctly

Comment: Yes, you are right. For the case of presented monoids with homogenous (in length) relators (like plactic or Chinese monoids), you must have a finite number of generators (infinite presentations may not work, but in some cases yes, see below). I did not know "right angled Artin monoids" (thanks :), are they related with braids? Note that "Property D" still holds for Cartier-Foata monoids with an infinite number of generators but, this time, due to the fact that the presentation is homogeneous in multidegree.

Comment: Yes I guess you may need finitely many relations (or carefully chosen relations) to keep the congruence classes finite.  Right angled Artin is the same as Cartier-Foata. It's just what group theorist call them because they are the Artin groups corresponding to right angled Coxeter groups.

Comment: Thanks, dear Benjamin, for the correspondence Right angled Artin <-> Cartier-Foata monoids, I can see it now (+1).

Comment: If you are willing to allow categories instead of monoids (with the obvious analogue of D) then the incidence algebera of a locally finite poset becomes such a thing

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes, of course, and I was thinking about these generalisations (which were considered early in applied math) and also about the work of G.-C. Rota on Möbius functions on categorical graphs, but I did not want to go so far because my question was usage and big-list oriented. Thank you for your comment which shows me that I have to make my purpose clearer (I'll add an edit later).

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in [my recent post https://mathoverflow.net/q/466095/510524.

Comment: @TianVlašić Yes, I am. Let me a couple of days to read and think. Thank you for pointing up this link.