# Generating functions in countable commutative monoids

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $f: \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function. The *power series* of $f$ can be viewed as the function $\mathscr{P}_f : q \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}^{} f(n)q^n$ where $q \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the aforementioned (non-formal) series is convergent. Note that for all $q \in \mathbb{C}$, $n \mapsto q^n$ is a monoid homomorphism from $(\mathbb{N}_0, +)$ to $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$. Also, if the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}^{} f(n)q^n$ converges to zero on some non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ must be the zero function.

On the other hand, let $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function. The *Dirichlet series* of $f$ can be viewed as the function $\mathscr{D}_f : s \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{} f(n)n^{-s}$ where $s \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the aforementioned (non-formal) series is convergent. Note that for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$, $n \mapsto n^{-s}$ is a monoid  homomorphism from $(\mathbb{N}, \cdot)$ to $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$. Also, if the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{} f(n)n^{-s}$ converges to zero on some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ must be the zero function.

Let $(M, \oplus)$ be a countably infinite commutative monoid and let $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a mapping. When $M$ is well-ordered, say by $\leq$, such that $(M, \leq)$ is a [locally-finite](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_poset#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20locally%20finite,can%20define%20its%20incidence%20algebra.) poset, we will define the series $\sum_{m \in M} f(m)$ as the limit of partial sums of $f(m)$ starting at the least element of $M$. Note that a well-ordering $\leq$ ensures that all elements of $M$ are arranged in a countable non-decreasing chain.

In the spirit of the observations mentioned above, we can introduce the following definition:

**Definition.** A *monoid with generating functions* is a countable commutative monoid $(M, \oplus)$ for which there exists a well order $\leq$ on $M$ such that $(M, \leq)$ is a locally-finite poset and for which there exists a non-empty subset $\Phi \subseteq \mathrm{Hom}((M,\oplus), (\mathbb{C}, \cdot))$ such that for every mapping $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and non-empty subset $U \subseteq \Phi$ open in the topology $\tau_{\Phi}$ of pointwise convergence on $\Phi$ induced by the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$, we have the implication:

$$\left (\forall \phi \in U : \sum_{m \in M}^{} f(m) \phi(m) = 0 \right ) \Rightarrow f=0.$$

Every such ordered quadruple $(M, \oplus, \leq, \Phi)$ will be called a *generating function system* (briefly, a *GFS*). We will only work in the topology $\tau_{\Phi}$ when considering a GFS $(M, \oplus, \leq, \Phi)$.

Given a mapping $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, we will define

$$\mathscr{C}(f)=\left \{ \phi \in \Phi : \sum_{m \in M}^{} f(m) \phi(m) \ \mathrm{converges} \right \}.$$

If $\mathscr{C}(f) \neq \emptyset$, we will call the resulting function $\mathscr{G}_{f} : \mathscr{C}(f) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined such that $\mathscr{G}_{f}(\phi)=\sum_{m \in M}^{} f(m) \phi(m)$ for all $\phi \in \mathscr{C}(f)$ the *generating function* of $f$.

A non-interesting example of a GFS would be a trivial monoid with its unique well order and homomorphism to $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$. My questions are the following:

**Question 1** (main question):

**Given a countable commutative monoid $(M, \oplus)$, a well order $\leq$ on $M$ such that $(M, \leq)$ is a locally-finite poset, and a non-empty subset $\Phi \subseteq \mathrm{Hom}((M,\oplus), (\mathbb{C}, \cdot))$, what is some sufficient condition on $\Phi$ for $(M, \oplus, \leq, \Phi)$ to be a GFS?**

A plausible approach could be to find a sufficient condition for generating functions to be analytic on some non-empty subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and apply the identity theorem for analytic functions. This might be done by indexing $\Phi$ by complex numbers and requiring analycity of monoid homomorphisms. However, I am not sure how to deduce the all coefficients of the zero function must be zero.

**Question 2:**

It is clear that the power series of every function $f: \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ converges on a region of $\mathbb{C}$ that is of empty interior if and only if it is the region $\left \{0 \right \}$. Similarly, it is clear that the Dirichlet series of every function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ converges on a region of $\mathbb{C}$ that is of empty interior if and only if it is the region $\emptyset$.

**I am interested in whether or not the following proposition holds:**

**Proposition.** *Let $(M, \oplus, \leq, \Phi)$ be a GFS, $e$ the identity element of $(M, \oplus)$, and let $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a mapping. If $\mathrm{int}\mathscr{C}(f)=\emptyset$, then $\mathscr{C}(f) \in \left \{\emptyset, \left \{\phi_0 \right \} \right \}$ where $\phi_0$ is the homomorphism defined such that $\phi_0(m)=0$ for all $m \in M \setminus \left \{e \right \}$.*

**NOTE:**

I have posted a similar question on MSE but had to delete it since it was admittedly very poorly stated. This is why I am writing this post. Anyhow, there, @Lukas Heger has noted how a similar theory, namely, [abstract analytic number theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_analytic_number_theory#:%7E:text=Abstract%20analytic%20number%20theory%20is,variety%20of%20different%20mathematical%20fields.), has been developed. Also, I would hereby like to thank @Sam Hopkins for bringing to my attention the notion of a [total algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_algebra) of a monoid which is connected to what I am doing here.

Your help in addressing any of the two questions (though **Question 1** is certainly of more importance to me) is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Okay, I removed that comment. I noticed you also deleted your question from MSE. There was another comment there which suggested you look into abstract analytic number theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_analytic_number_theory), as an already developed theory which may be similar to what you are trying to achieve here. This would be a more analytic flavored approach than my algebraic suggestion of the total algebra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_algebra). From the many corrections you've had to make here, you can see why using an existing theory might be preferable.

Comment: If you're interested in convergence properties of power series and Dirichlet series, you might also want to look at "generalized Dirichlet series" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series) which can incorporate both.

Comment: Please be aware that every edit of a question or of one of its answers bumps the thread to the front page.
This has happened for this thread already more than 20 times in just a few days, and this is a nuisance
for other users. Please refrain from unnecessary edits to your posts. -- Usually, the vast majority of
minor edits can be avoided by writing and proofreading a question carefully before posting it.

Comment: @StefanKohl Thank you for this, there were quite some issues with this question that are now resolved.

Comment: In the definition of $\mathscr{C}(f)$, the expression $\sum_{m \in M}^{} f(m) \phi(m) < \infty$ is quite incomprehensible. Do you mean that $\sum_{m \in M}^{} f(m) \phi(m)$ is convergent ? or that $\sum_{m \in M}^{} |f(m) \phi(m)| < \infty$ ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Thank you, any convergence in this post is conditional.

Comment: I insist a bit: $\mathscr{C}(f)=\left \{ \phi \in \Phi : \sum_{m \in M}^{} f(m) \phi(m) < \infty \right \}.$ has really NO meaning, sorry. The reason is that all the partial sums take their values in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I agree, fixed.

Comment: Any locally finite well ordering is either finite or (canonically) isomorphic to that of $\mathbb{N}$ so that, with your hypotheses, there is a unique indexing of $M$ as a strictly increasing sequence $(m_n)_{n\ge0}$. This implies, in particular, that your monoid is countably infinite (this hypothesis is redundant).

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Is this clarification OK?

Comment: How is it strictly increasing? I mean, when indexing the whole of $M$?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Note that $M$ could be finite.

Comment: I insist a bit [Note that a well-ordering $\leq$ ensures that all elements of $M$ can be arranged in a countable non-decreasing chain.] ----> I suggest to to replace your "can" by "are" or add "(in general in several ways)" because your setting is order-dependent. What is your opinion ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. OK, I agree.